# Error in an Outlook addin 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin

I have developed an Outlook addin where a ribbon will be loaded while opening '*Appoinment*' window.

While running the application, the ribbon works fine. But if I open any mail item, it prompts the following error message.

```
'Error occurred while calling the callback ribbon_getdcvisible'
```

I am able to disable the error message, but I want to know how to get rid of this error permanently without disabling the error message?

Comment: I have developed the outlook addin using ribbon designer

Comment: And what is your ribbon_getdcvisible callback implementation? Can you put a breakpoint there?

Comment: I have not implemented ribbon_getvisible callback function, just added a ribbon using ribbon designer and included two ribbon buttons and implemented click functionality for those buttons

Comment: What other addins do you have installed? Do you have BCM?

Comment: I have not installed any other addins except built-in addins, sorry i dint get you, can you pls explain me more

Comment: Googleing that error produces a few hits where Business Contact Manager (BCM) caused that problem. If you do not have ribbon_getdcvisible callback, some other addin does.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your callback methods exist in correct assembly and accepts the correct parameters. In your case the callback method should look like following.

```
public bool ribbon_getdcvisible(IRibbonControl control)
{
// your code here.
}
```